# How to get access to child component?

Tags: angular

I have a component that accepts a `config` object and redners form inside:

```
 <dynamic-form (submitted)="formSubmitted($event)" [config]="config">
          <div class="actions">
            <button pButton type="button" (click)="add()">Добавить</button>
            <button pButton type="button" (click)="cancel()">Отмена</button>
          </div>
        </dynamic-form>
```

This component has `form`:

```
  public form: FormGroup;
```

How to get access to this `form` outside from parent component and submit form (or any actions with form)?

I can place button inside and emit Output. But I need to do that more flexibale to change buttons

Maybe it is wrong archirecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way I could think of is `@ViewChild`, Using `@ViewChild` get access to the child component, and access form or any property of the component(example below).

```
@ViewChild(DynamicFormComponent) dynamicFormComponent: DynamicFormComponent;

someAction() {
  console.log(this.dynamicFormComponent.form);
}
```

Use `@ViewChildren` if you have multiple child components(Example Below)

```
@ViewChildren(DynamicFormComponent) dynamicFormComponents: QueryList<DynamicFormComponent>;
```

Comment: How to get  access to ```form.valid``` to use in [disabled] button?

Comment: You have access to form in `dynamicFormComponent.form`, Simply add this for `[disabled]="dynamicFormComponent.form.valid"`